# MySQL like on special characters which are not present

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This is probably a very strange question but here goes I have a tv listing page which displays a list of shows by Genre. My Genre column value for each show looks like this (text string):

```
Adventure, Action & Adventure, Sci-Fi & Fantasy
```

Now if I do a search for Adventure I get back the correct results, but if I have special characters in between I get no results see below:

```
$query .= "
SELECT t1.*, 
t2.content as genres
FROM tvshows as t1
LEFT JOIN tvshows_content as t2 ON t2.tvshows_id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'genres'
WHERE (t2.content LIKE "%,sci fi fantasy,%" OR t2.content LIKE "sci fi fantasy,%" OR t2.content LIKE "%,sci fi fantasy" OR t2.content = "sci fi fantasy" OR t2.content LIKE "%sci fi fantasy%" OR t2.content LIKE "sci-fi-fantasy" ) ";
```

My question is that I remove special characters for page slugs, but I want to check if they maybe present? Is this possible?

Comment: You should probably look into mysql full text search and now in V 5.7.6 n-gram parser is introduced http://mysqlserverteam.com/innodb-full-text-n-gram-parser/

Comment: Very bad design of database. Read about database normalization, if you don't want to end with serious  performance problem using that LIKE will cause.

Comment: If you persist with this model, then there really is no point using an RDBMS at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you actually can't find results searching for 'Action & Adventure' then it is not the problem, that you are using a special character, it is more likely, that you are using different character encodings in field and query. You could try the `BINARY` operator for this, but you could try a different optimization first.

Have a look at the SQL query you are using:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.content as genres FROM tvshows as t1
LEFT JOIN tvshows_content as t2 ON t2.tvshows_id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'genres'
WHERE (
  t2.content LIKE "%,sci-fi-fantasy,%" OR 
  t2.content LIKE "sci-fi-fantasy,%" OR 
  t2.content LIKE "%,sci-fi-fantasy" OR 
  t2.content = "sci-fi-fantasy" OR 
  t2.content LIKE "%sci-fi-fantasy%" OR 
  t2.content LIKE "sci-fi-fantasy" 
)
```

you are doing a lot there to make sure, that the genre you are searching for might be in the beginning or the end of the list. There are two different approaches to this. One nice one is `FIND_IN_SET` which is made for searching comma separated strings:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.content as genres FROM tvshows as t1
LEFT JOIN tvshows_content as t2 ON t2.tvshows_id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'genres'
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('sci-fi-fantasy',t2.content) > 0
```

But here he you have to make sure that your queries character encoding matches fields character encoding if you want to search for i.e. umlaut. Give it a try and if it does not work, or you can't match your encodings, then you can use another way - a bit less elegant - by concating the commas to the genre field beforehand, this way you also only have to search for one variant:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.content as genres FROM tvshows as t1
LEFT JOIN tvshows_content as t2 ON t2.tvshows_id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'genres'
WHERE CONCAT(',',t2.content,',') LIKE "%,sci-fi-fantasy,%"
```

But here you can also use the BINARY operator if you need umlaut, special chars, etc. and can't match encodings:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.content as genres FROM tvshows as t1
LEFT JOIN tvshows_content as t2 ON t2.tvshows_id = t1.id AND t2.type = 'genres'
WHERE BINARY CONCAT(',',t2.content,',') LIKE "%,sci-fi-fantasy,%"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great thanks your answer was "Exactly" what I was looking for constructive and informative.